# Flutter webrtc screen sharing

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc

I have a flutter project (iOS, Android) that uses WebRTC. I need to send video from camera (working correctly) and screen capture by WebRTC. How to share the screen on WebRTC with the flutter_webrtc package?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you please share the demo url for screen share?

Comment: [WebRTC repo](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-Video-Calling-App) and [callPage](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-Video-Calling-App/blob/master/lib/screens/call_page.dart) @Hardik1344

Comment: thank you sir,
I want to add screen share functionality. 
is it available in your repo sir?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the flutter_webrtc plugin and do like this method ( use getDisplayMedia method in webRTC to get display ) :

```
class ScreenSharing {
  MediaStream? _localStream;
  final RTCVideoRenderer _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();

  Future<void> _makeScreenSharing() async {
    final mediaConstraints = <String, dynamic>{'audio': true, 'video': true};

    try {
      var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(mediaConstraints);

      _localStream = stream;
      _localRenderer.srcObject = _localStream;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share full demo example if you have?

Comment: @Mojtaba Ghiasi were you able to run this on iOS and Android? For me it only functions well for desktop browsers.